# Flutter, how to get rid of raisedButton bottom margin?

Tags: flutter, dart

So I'm trying to remove the bottom margin of raisedButton so it will look like it is merged with the card below it.
here's what it looks like[image: here]

here is my code

```
Expanded(
          child: Card(
            elevation: 5,
            // shape:
            //     RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(22)),
            child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Text("Apakah anak sudah bisa ... ?",
                            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: RaisedButton(
                            child: Text(
                              "Iya",
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                            color: Colors.green[300],
                            onPressed: () {}),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                          child: RaisedButton(
                              child: Text(
                                "Tidak",
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                              color: Colors.red[200],
                              onPressed: () {}))
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
          ),
        )
```

or do you guys have any other alternative solution to achieve that?

Comment: I'm not sure you can get rid of that margin without changing source file, I would suggest you to create your own button using `InkWell`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicitly set your [Row](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Row-class.html) height to match the height of your [RaisedButton](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RaisedButton-class.html). Simply wrap it inside a [Container](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html) and add the `height` attribute.

If you want to, you can access the default height by using `Theme.of(context).buttonTheme.height`. [Theme.of](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Theme/of.html) returns the `ThemeData` used in the current context.

Here a minimal example:

[image: Demo]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          body: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: Card(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('Test'),
                Container(
                  height: Theme.of(context).buttonTheme.height,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      RaisedButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        child: Text('Yes'),
                        color: Colors.green,
                      ),
                      RaisedButton(
                        onPressed: (){},
                        child: Text('No'),
                        color: Colors.red,
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )
          ),
        ),
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. NikasPor's answer didnt work for me, unfortunately. The way I fixed it is by seeting the crossAxisAlignment on the row to .stretch

```
Row(
   crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
   children:[ /* Buttons Here */]
)
```